How to play a file recorded by GStreamer filesink?
I recorded a udp stream using gtreamer:
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc address=230.1.1.1 port=1720 multicast-iface=eth0 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! filesink location=test.h264

How can i now play the recorded file "test.h264"?
The file is unplayable using vlc and ffplay.
vlc test.h264
ffplay -i test.h264

I also tried to use gstreamer to play the file:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

But this gets stuck at Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
How can i recover the recorded stream?

There is no test.h264 to check what's wrong. You need to provide a link to a small testable file.

Just as info you decode the h264 Stream so your file would be a raw video. It is more a file that contains a series of raw frames. Remove avdec and write h264 directly to file

There's an error on your recording pipe, you are decoding the H264. So you are actually saving a RAW file. Try this one:
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc address=230.1.1.1 port=1720 multicast-iface=eth0 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, encoding-name=H264 ! rtph264depay ! filesink location=test.h264


Thank you this helps with future recordings. However is there a way to recover the current recordings?
